# Empty document when JavaScript used through IE using Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I’m writing a script automating useless tasks at work. 
Usually, everything is ok but sometimes a JavaScript is run in order to load specific pages and then all my documents are empty.

Exemple:

```
$Page = New-Object -ComObject «InternetExplorer.Application»
...
$frame = $Page.document.frames
...

# The script navigates well, set some values get others everything is fine and then:

$frame.item(3).IHTMLDocument3_getElementById(«oAff1»).children[0].(...).click()

# It does the click, the browser loads the new page and:

$frame.item(3).document

# Returns nothing, it seems to load in IE but not for Powershell who still see a white page.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems you are assuming that after you click...the object will remain the same, probably it returns you nothing because this value is null under the "New object" after loading the page. My advice is that you do a step-by-step execution and when you are about to hit `$frame.item(3).document` check what $frame has on it on the command line, most likely you need to reload some variables to get what you need again

Comment: Looks like you need to reassign the object for $frame.item(3).document. You can also check the null value of $frame.item(3).document to avoid an error.

Comment: You are right, the document is now readable :-) but I get a new exception... Now when I try to find an Element in my frame I get an Ambigus Name exception. I don’t understand why? My object is identified (i can read the document) so why it become ambigus when searching an element in it?

Comment: Try to provide the script and HTML code with Iframe code and detailed error message. We will try to test the issue and try to provide further suggestions.